# pass arguments when pipe is called inside a function

Tags: r, dplyr, magrittr

I wanted to write a function that is the composition of two functions using the pipe operator `%>%`, so that, for instance, the following are equivalent (imagine I call it `%O%`):

```
iris[1:4] %>% lapply(FUN = function(x) hist(sample(x))
iris[1:4] %>% lapply(FUN = sample %O% hist)
```

I want it in this direction (not `hist %O% sample`) because it would follow the same logic as `%>%`.

I've come to something like that:

```
'%O%' <- function(lhs1, rhs1){
    return(
        function(x){
            return(x %>% lhs1 %>% rhs1)
    })
}
```

However, it raises errors when I try

```
iris[1:4] %>% lapply(FUN = sample(size = 100, replace = TRUE) %O% hist)
```

What should I do to allow the parameters to be understood by `%>%` inside the `%O%` function? Is it an `eval` and `quote` problem? I also don't really understand how `%>%` is able to read arguments in `lhs` and `rhs`.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `magrittr` functional sequence instead?

```
f <- . %>% sample() %>% hist()

iris[1:4] %>% lapply(f)
```

Or just

```
iris[1:4] %>% lapply(. %>% sample() %>% hist())
```

Comment: Thanks, thats all I needed. Didnt know I could define functions like that. `magrittr` is awesome!

Answer (score 2):

Here are some possibilities:

```
iris[1:4] %>% lapply(FUN = function(x) x %>% sample %>% hist) 

library(gsubfn)
iris[1:4] %>% fn$lapply(FUN = x ~ x %>% sample %>% hist)

library(functional)
iris[1:4] %>% lapply(FUN = Compose(sample, hist))

library(functional)
`%c%` <- Compose
iris[1:4] %>% lapply(FUN = sample %c% hist)
```

**Update:** Added additional solutions.

Comment: didnt know about these libraries ty! Magrittr seems to do the work pretty good as well. Thanks!